# Перевести число в строку в C++

Tags: c++

Нужно ввести число с клавиатуры и перевести его в строку без использования встроенных и любых вспомогательных функций в C++. Очень нужна помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: @veldon, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @veldon: Совсем без встроенных функций не получится — как же вы иначе память для строки аллоцируете?

Comment: @VladD самому как-то перевести, может и не совсем.

Comment: Скорей всего это задача с ассемблерной вставкой.

Comment: @veldon, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

[@veldon](/users/24305/veldon), общий алгоритм для целых чисел -- пока число больше или равно основанию системы счисления, делите число на нее и записываете остатки в строку.

Потом дописываете оставшееся значение числа (это будет последняя цифра) и реверсируете строку (последний символ (цифра) становится  первым, а первый последним). Вот и почти все.

Остались детали с начальным анализом не отрицательно ли число и не равно ли оно минимально возможному (тут будет некое ответвление в алгоритме) для данного типа целых.

Память достаточного размера (скажем, 20 байт) может предоставить вызывающая программа.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, так:

```
int Value=1234567;
string Result=(string)Value;
```

Comment: @ms301, так даже не скомпилируется. 


Если же "обмануть" компилятор и в ответ на его притензии написать

    string Result=(const char *)Value;

то все равно ничего хорошего не выйдет (программа при запуске упадет).